# How to pass Integer value in Vue router 4 props

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vite, vue-router4

I'm working with vue router 4, I've got an error when I'm passing post id to post details page via router props, it

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "destinationId". Expected Number with value 1, got String with value "1"

Now my questions is how can I pass the id as Integer? it's passing as String.

Here is my router file:

```
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'HomeRoute',
  component: HomeView
},
{
  path: '/details/:slug/',
  name: 'DestinationDetails',
  component: () => import('../views/DestinationDetails.vue'),
  props: route => ({...route.params , slug: route.params.slug}),
  children: [
    {
      path: ':exprienceSlug',
      name: 'experience.show',
      component: () => import('../views/PlaceDetails.vue'),
      props: route => ({...route.params,}),
    },
  ]
},
{
  path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
  name: "NotFound",
  component: () => import('../views/NotFound.vue'),
}
```

]

And Here is my Post file where form I'm passing the params via router-link tag

```
<router-link  class="col-md-3"
            v-for="experience in destination.experiences" 
            :key="experience.id" 
            :to="{name: 'experience.show', params: {exprienceSlug: experience.slug, destinationId: destination.id}}">

                <PlacesCard :places="experience"/>
            </router-link>
```

And this is post single page where I'm catching the id and fetch the posts.

```
props: {
        destinationId: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 0,
        },
        exprienceSlug: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        destination(){
            return storeData.destinations.find(
                destination => destination.id == this.destinationId
            )
        },
        experience(){
            return this.destination.experiences.find(
                experience => experience.slug == this.exprienceSlug
            )
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

`route.params` are of type `string | string[]`.
But you can change that by parsing the params:

```
children: [
{
  path: ':exprienceSlug',
  name: 'experience.show',
  component: () => import('../views/PlaceDetails.vue'),
  props: ({ params }: Route) => ({
    ...route.params,
    destinationId: Number(params.destinationId)
  }),
},
```

]